# Random dropout rates for tf.nn.dropout

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, dropout

I am experimenting with the TensorFlow dropout function. Since a functionality where the dropout rate decreases with time during training was too complicated to implement (tried all day yesterday), I thought using random dropout rates for each iteration could also be a good idea.

I tried the following line:

```
X = tf.nn.dropout(X, tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([], 0.4,0.95)))
```

For using random dropout rates between 0.4 and 0.95 during training. This did not work out, I got the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value generator_1/Variable
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

okay, i fixed it. It must be :

```
X = tf.nn.dropout(X, tf.random_uniform([], 0.4,0.95))
```

tf.Variable is not necessary. Can close that.